# Will Android kill a Service if I uncheck "Show notification" option on Settings?

Tags: notifications, stock-android, services

I was just wondering: will Android kill a Service (that uses persistent notification to keep itself alive) if I uncheck "Show notifications" on app settings?

I am running Lollipop 5.1.

Comment: We need more information. What is the app that is persistent? Is it system or user app? Is it the notification service or other? Answers will be incomplete without those details.

Comment: **Note**: This question is related to [this changes on JellyBean 4.3 for running background service & persistent notification](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/29/android-engineer-explains-why-some-apps-suddenly-have-persistent-notifications-after-you-upgrade-to-android-4-3/)

Comment: @HasH_BrowN it is a user app. This question is not app-specific, but if you want exemples : AcDisplay (Active mode enabled), GravityScreen. I didn't understand, what to you mean by "notification service or other ?". It is a notification (in the status bar) that " keeps the service alive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling notification would not terminate the life cycle of apps, nor would apps use persistent notification to keep themselves alive. Normally background operations would be done in the background, and notification provides a means to display the result back to the user via the main UI thread. Notification in this context refers to elements such as *toasts* (pop-up messages) and any icon the app might display in the status bar. In any case, the operation would have finished regardless of whether or not notification must be shown.

Comment: Si if I have a service that use a persistent notification, Android won't kill it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but I'm about 99%. If the app was made to run in the background disabling notifications shouldn't affect anything else. It should only prevent the app from pushing *notifications*.